# How to create a measure that can mark two columns conditionally?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that is something like this:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1H4 |  |  |
| 6S8 | True |  |
| 1L7 |  | True |
| 6T8 | True |  |
| 7Y8 |  |  |
| 6S2 | True | True |
| 1H1 |  | True |
| 6S3 | True |  |
| 1H9 | True | True |
| 6S0 |  |  |

I want to create a measure that evaluates a table to be able to conditionally (to later make conditional rules for report i.e. place color values in such cells) evaluate the cells for the following 2 conditions:

1. when there are values in both Column A and Column B
2. when there are blanks/nulls in both columns

(If both can be done in a single measure this would be ideal)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure like this:

```
Background Color = 

var Count_A = COUNTBLANK('Table'[A])
var Count_B = COUNTBLANK('Table'[B])

RETURN 
    SWITCH(TRUE();
    AND(Count_A = 0; Count_B = 0); "Red";
    AND(Count_A > 0; Count_B > 0); "Green";
    "")
```

First [count the blank values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countblank-function-dax) in each of the columns, and then return a different color, depending on both counts. Then use this measure to [conditionally format the background color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) for each of the columns:

[image]

to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom column with the logic of

```
Column name =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    A = 'True'
        && B = 'True', "True",
    A = ''
        && B = '', "False",
    "Else goes here"
)
```

You'll have to change the logic if the cells without anything in them are '' or true blanks. [SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) acts like a multiple IF statement, and Switch with TRUE() evaluates the conditions in the later steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by using both custom columns and measures.

1. Custom Column

   ```
   Column =
   IF (
     Table[A] <> BLANK ()
     && Table[B] <> BLANK (),
     "Green",
        IF ( Table[A] = BLANK () && Table[B] = BLANK (), "Red" )
      )
   ```

[image: Column Output]

2. Measure

   ```
    Measure X = 
   IF(COUNTBLANK(Table[A]) = 0  
      && COUNTBLANK(Table[B]) = 0 , "#00FF00", 
          IF(COUNTBLANK(Table[A]) <> 0   
             && COUNTBLANK(Table[B]) <> 0 , "#FF0000")
    )
   ```
3. After creating a measure or custom column go to conditional formatting and select background colour, and you may select either measure or column as per your choice. this will give you the desired result.

[image: Background ID]

Output

[image: Measure Output]